# Объявление переменной ломает код

Tags: c, указатели, память, filestream

Здесь работающий код, который выводит строки из текстового файла

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* f = fopen("../Help/in1.txt", "r");
    if(f == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found");
        return 1;
    }
    char* line;
    while(fscanf(f, "%s\n", line) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Если добавить в любое место строчку типа `int i = 0;`, то код завершается с ошибкой 0xC0000005. Почему это происходит и как это исправить?

Code::Blocks 16.01, GNU GCC

Comment: UPD: код не ломается если строчку вставить после цикла

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если размер вашего считываемого файла in1.txt заранее известен, например 200 символов, то выделите память для line статически, то есть вместо

```
char * line;
```

напишите:

```
char line[201];// строки в си заканчиваются нулём, поэтому 200 + 1
```

Если размер считываемого файла заранее не известен, выделяем память динамически:

```
char * line;
char symwol;
int i = 0;
line = malloc(sizeof(char)); //выделили память для одного символа

while (fread(&symwol, sizeof(char), 1, f) == 1){ //цикл выполняется до конца файла
    line[i] = symwol;//запишем считанный символ в строку
    i++;
    line = realloc(line, sizeof(char) * i + 1);//увеличили размер выделенного блока
    }
line[i] = 0;//не забываем, что строки в си должны заканчиваться нулём
fclose(f);
printf("%s\n", line);
free(line);//освобождаем выделенную память
```

Comment: Для общего развития. Обычно людям лень набирать много букв и для чтение одного символа они используют [fgetc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) / Кстати, если надо читать строки неопределенного размера и вы используете GCC (очень много людей на всех платформах юзают именно его), то читать строки, размещаемые в динамической памяти (как и у вас malloc/realloc) можно функцией [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)

Comment: 1. Кривость: одинаковый `fread` делается в двух местах для того, чтобы обойти проблемы цикла `while (!feof(f))`. Лучше: не создавать эти проблемы вообще, т.е. не использовать циклы предусловием `while (!feof(f))`. Управляющих проверок `feof(f)` в программе на C не должно быть вообще. 2. Кривость: для чего в начале кода вдруг делается `malloc(sizeof(char))`??? Лучше: просто `line = NULL`.

Comment: @AnT спасибо за конструктивную критику, ответ отредактировал. Есть вопрос о кривости номер 2: если не инициализировать указатель line malloc'ом и пытаться реаллоцировать память происходит сегфолт. То же самое, если инициализировать line NULL'ем. Можно поподробнее, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Моя "Кривость 2" - несколько "мимо кассы". Я не заметил, что вы сначала делаете запись символа, а только затем `realloc`. В такой ситуации конечно нужен начальный `malloc`.

Comment: @Rudolf Diesel Если файл не из /dev то можно просто его открыть, посчитать размер и намолочиться)

Answer (score 4):

Застолье. Жена все теребит мужа, который пьет все, что на столе стоит и горит :)
- Вася, ну съешь хоть что-то! Хоть пирожок!

Через полчаса Вася соглашается, жует пирожок и валится под стол со словами - "вот что твой пирожок сделал!"

```
char * line;
while(fscanf(f, "%s\n", line)
```

Вот та бутылка, к которой вы прикладываетесь - чтение в никуда! Потому что неинициализированная переменная `line` содержит мусор, а не указатель на достаточное для чтения количество памяти.

А `int i = 0;` - просто пирожок...

Comment: Инициализация line пустой строкой приводит к той же ошибке

Comment: Конечно. Потому что нужно выделить **достаточное количество** памяти для чтения из файла, да еще и памяти не r/o, которой вполне может оказаться литерал (это предугадывая ваш следующий вопрос :)) Инициализация пустой строкой указывает на однобайтный буфер, который к тому же `const`...

Comment: Интересно почему тогда оно работает без ошибок в том варианте, который изложен в вопросе

Comment: Если вы переходите в неположенном месте дорогу - то, перейдя, вы как - удивляетесь "и почему это меня машина не сбила?"? Undefined behaviour. По-русски - неопределенное поведение. Именно неопределенное - может сработать, может программу завалить, может привести к тому, что совершенно другой код в другом месте работать перестанет...

Comment: @Vincent_Hawks: Вам лишь *показалось*, что оно работает.